# Does used Apple hardware comes with macOS license?

Tags: macos, license

I have been on eBay, looking for a used Mac mini and to my surprise it said, the system comes without any operation system (disk erased). It is still an Apple product and I wonder, is it possible to not have a "right" to at least an older (original sold) version of macOS?

A good answer would hence point out the aspects:

1. Can Apple computers be bought without a license?
2. Can Apple macOS licenses be transfered in a way that a Apple Computer ends up without an OS?

*update*

A comment suggested specifying the model of the Mac Mini. As suggested the product was seen on ebay, where vendors not always care/are able to provide a model number. This being said, the Mac Mini in question was described as only using its hardware attributes:

> Apple MAC MINI 1,66 GHz Intel Core Duo

Considering the comment/ request about the model, an answer could highlight if the OS / OS license is depending on the model/product?